# SwiftUI and lists with coreData, unexpected behavior, why it delete another row, not I selected

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I have problem with onDelete{}. when I tried to delete single row from list that contains data from coreData, it deleted the above row, not the row I want. ViewModel contains the array

```
 @ObservedObject var delegate = ViewModel()

            ForEach(delegate.notes) { note in
                VStack(alignment:.leading){
                Text(note.toDo!)
                Text(note.datee!)
                    .font(Font.system(size: 9))
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    
                }
            }.onDelete(perform: removeNote)`

 @FetchRequest(
    entity: Note.entity(),
    sortDescriptors: [
        NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Note.toDo, ascending: true),
    ]
)
var notes : FetchedResults<Note>
func removeNote(offsets: IndexSet){
    for index in offsets{
        let note = notes[index]
   //     delegate.context.perform {
   
        delegate.context.delete(note)
        do{
            try delegate.context.save()
            delegate.refresh()
        }catch{}
      //  }
    }
```

Comment: for more details: when I put the first note and the second note, and then I deleted the first one, and put another one then delete the latest one coreData delete the second one not the third note I want to delete

Comment: what does `delegate.refresh()` do? Why do you have to refresh? When the note is deleted SwiftUI would automatically remove it from showing. You don't have to anything special. Can you comment out  `delegate.refresh()` and try? Also small suggestion don't call it `delegate`

Comment: Once you do the above, also create a function in your model `func delete(notes: [Note])`. Let the model do the work deleting and use `context.perform` / `context.performAndWait` when working with any core data objects

Comment: that what happened when I commented out delegate.refresh() -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray"

Comment: when I commented out delegate,refresh() and did context.performAndWait, it worked but the list still not refreshed. I have to leave notes view and access it again.

Comment: I found the solution when I tried to change fetching data into the array of notes by this line: var notes : FetchedResults<Note>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  @FetchRequest(
    sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Note.toDo, ascending: true)],
    animation: .default)
var notes : FetchedResults<Note>
 private func removeNote(offsets: IndexSet) {
    withAnimation {
        offsets.map { notes[$0] }.forEach(delegate.context.delete)

        do {
            try delegate.context.save()
        } catch {
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```